# Response entity and response in client differ

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I've got a Spring REST web application. I've got a method which returns a response entity.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/shoes", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getShoes() {

    Collection<Shoes> shoes = shoesService.findAll();

    ResponseEntity responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(shoes, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on the last line, I can see that the `responseEntity` contains a list of the following objects:

> Shoes{id=1, localization=Localization{id=1, city='Denver'}, category=Category{id=1, name='wellingtons', group='male'}, size=9}

But when I send the request in client app, I get a JSON, which contains only id and size:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "size": 9
}
```

I wonder why I don't receive localization and category.

Here is the `Shoes` class:

```java
@Table(name = "shoes")
public class Shoes{

    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    private Localization localization;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private int size;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have bi-directional associations, you have to declare which object has the role of parent (annotated with [`JsonManagedReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html)) and which has the role of child (annotated with [`JsonBackReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html)) to break cycles.

You annotated both properties (`localization`, `category`) to not be serialized, see [`JsonBackReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html):

> Annotation used to indicate that associated property is part of two-way linkage between fields; and that its role is "child" (or "back") link. Value type of the property must be a bean: it can not be a Collection, Map, Array or enumeration. Linkage is handled such that the property annotated with this annotation is not serialized; and during deserialization, its value is set to instance that has the "managed" (forward) link.